# Can you make a variable with a variable name?

Tags: c#, .net

So what I want to try and do is a thing you can do in javascript. I want to be able to add a child to some sort of object but I want the name of that child to be variable. In javascript you can do something like

```
const obj = new Object();

let childName = "child1";

obj[childName] = new Object();
```

Is something like this possible in C#?

Comment: sometimes it's an indication you have an XY problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string,object> obj = new Dictionary<string,object>();
string childName = "child1";
obj[childName] = new Object();
```

If you know the type of the objects you want to add to your dictionary, you can also specify it. For example, if you want to use only integers, you could write `Dictionary<string,int>` and then you don't need casting.

Comment: Definately seem like what i'm looking for

Comment: I would note that while this might be useful in some cases, using actual typed properties would be preferable in statically typed languages like c#. I.e. Using Javascript coding style in c# is probably not a good idea.